# rotating a linear equation about the $x$ axis

Tags: calculus

I am really having a hard time doing this problem its taking a lot of work to try to figure this out.

Find the volume of the solid generated by rotating about the x-axis the region bounded by the curves
$y=e^{10x}+e^{−10x}$, $x=0, x=6$, and the $x$-axis.

I tried integrating $\pi(r)^2$ from $0$ to $6$ using $e^{10x}+e^{-10x}$ as the radius but i cant get the right answer am I doing something wrong here? what steps do I need to take to actually get a right answer?

Comment: You should write down what the resulting integral looks like after squaring that equation, did you foil it in order to square it?

Answer (score 1):

Doing exactly what you say you did would give $\pi \int_0^6 (e^{10x}+ e^{-10x})^2 dx= \pi \int_0^6 (e^{20x}+ 2+ e^{-20x}) dx$

I don't see anything difficult about it.   What did you get when you integrated that?

Comment: i got pi(12+(sinh(120)/10)) and it is saying thats wrong do you have any advice?

Comment: If you are using something like WebAssign where you have to type in the answer, you may need to use the exponential form instead of $sinh$.

Comment: I tried using that format, and it still didn't accept my answer.